# I want to play multiple audio files with the same button in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, avplayer, nsurl

Im trying to develop an app that could systematically play different audio files when a button is pressed.

For example, If I press the button once then it will play "sound file 1"
and If I press the button a second time it will play "sound file 2"

Ive looked over apple's developer page but that lead nowhere. 
  If anyone can give me a hand that would be great.

Comment: the code has to be in objective c

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a counter and check its value depending on how many times you tapped the button . Here is working simple swift code.

```
var counter = 0

@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    counter = counter + 1
    counter = counter % 4 //When counter becomes 4 then return back to 0

    if counter == 1 {
    println("play sound 1")
    }else if counter == 2{
    println("play sound 2")
    }else if counter == 3 {
    println( "play sound 3" )
    }
```

Objective C Version:

```
   int counter = 0;

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    counter = counter + 1;
    counter = counter % 4 ;//When counter becomes 4 then return back to 0

    if (counter == 1) {
        NSLog(@"play sound 1");
    }else if (counter == 2){
        NSLog(@"play sound 2");
    }else if (counter == 3) {
        NSLog(@"play sound 3");
    }
```

Comment: Can someone come up with a script similar to this in objective c?

Comment: Added Objective C version

Comment: It gives me an error... it highlights the     - (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender { in red and tells me missing context for method declaration.

Comment: Just paste this code into your view controller and connect to your button on interface builder.

Comment: Did you add anything on header .h file?

Comment: .h file: //
//  ViewController.h
//  TRUMP
//
//  Created by Nate Camorlinga on 8/30/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Nate Camorlinga. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController




-(IBAction) trump;












end

Comment: .m file://


interface ViewController ()

end

implementation ViewController


int counter = 0;

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {

    counter = counter + 1;
    counter = counter % 4 ;//When counter becomes 4 then return back to 0
    
    if (counter == 1) {
        NSLog(@"play sound 1");
    }else if (counter == 2){
        NSLog(@"play sound 2");
    }else if (counter == 3) {
        NSLog(@"play sound 3");
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
end

Comment: create a new single view application project. Just copy/past the code into your .m file (dont add anything or any connection to .h file) and go to your Interface builder add a new button and tied it to action in .m file. Once you understand how things work then you can implement it to your project.